# c# windows form- How remove txt all line where available $ or ! or >?

Tags: regex, split, streamreader

txt file available lots line in there some line I need remove.

Please see txt file some line

```
adrian
jenkinson
adri
abby
abigal
adrian$
abbby%
jennefer!
jennef%
jenn^
```

so I need solution how I am regex using to delete all symbol character full line from the txt file?

Comment: use regex `/[^A-Za-z\d\s]+/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `/[^A-Za-z\d\s]+/`

It will match character except

1. Letters (A-Za-z)
2. Digits (\d)
3. White line, new line, tab space,etc... (\s)

**Explanation :**

```
[^A-Za-z\d\s]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cw6GVH6qoGTMnUDW)

Comment: can you provide what code I am using in windows form application area for remove symbol line?

Comment: @dorislindquist are are using C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = text.Split('\n');
var newLines = (from line in lines
               where !line.Contains('$') && !line.Contains('!') && !line.Contains('>')
               select line).ToArray();
var newText = string.Empty;
for (var i = 0; i < newLines.Length - 1; i++)
     newText += newLines[i] + Environment.NewLine;
newText += newLines[newLines.Length - 1];
```

newText = your new text without those lines.